# Using WHERE clause in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the table design for a cartitems table

**cartitems**

```
cartitem_id PK AI
customer_id FK
item_id FK UNIQUE 
item_quantity INT DEFAULT 1
```

What I need to accomplish

1.) if `item_id` exists in the table, increment the `item_quantity` by **1** everytime user clicks on "**Add To Cart**" button for the **same** `item_id`

2.) if `item_id` doesn't yet exist in the table, run an insert statement.

So what I did is this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addItemToCart`(aCustomerId int, aProductId int)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO cart_items(customer_id,product_id) 
        VALUES(aCustomerId,aProductId)

        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        item_quantity = item_quantity + 1

        WHERE customer_id = aCustomerId AND item_id = aProductId;
    END
```

But when I inspected it, I get an error that says, `missing semicolon` at `item_quantity = item_quantity + 1`

I can't figure out what's causing the error. I don't know if it's a problem with the `WHERE` clause.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is well explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row

Looking at your table, you want to increment the quantity of an item for a given customer's cart.  I am assuming here that a customer may only have one shopping cart at a time.  So the conditions under which you want MySQL to perform an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT` is when the customer *and* item *already* appear in the table.

Towards this end, you can create a unique index on these two columns via:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_item_index ON cart_items (customer_id, item_id);
```

Then, you can use the following `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO cart_items (customer_id, item_id)
VALUES
    (aCustomerId, anItemId)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
item_quantity = item_quantity + 1

WHERE customer_id = aCustomerId AND
      item_id = anItemId;
```

Now the behavior will be that if a new entry for customer/item comes in, the `item_quantity` will be set to the default value of `1`, otherwise the `item_quantity` will be incremented by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cart_items WHERE item_id = aProductId)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cart_items(customer_id,product_id) 
  VALUES(aCustomerId,aProductId)
END
ELSE  
  UPDATE cart_items SET item_quantity = item_quantity + 1 WHERE customer_id = aCustomerId AND item_id = aProductId;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use that `WHERE` clause there? It doesn't make sense. If `DUPLICATE KEY` happens it will UPDATE whatever field you specified to the old record that has the same key. So, if you just remove `WHERE` clause it should work. Check [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). It states the following two:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

are the same.

Comment: I have an instance where I also update the editor and edit_date, but I only want the actual values to be updated if they are changed, so I also need to say "only update if these specific values get changed"